# Get the id From another component with the Link using Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pokeapi

I'm making a project with the PokeAPI using vue, I have 3 components, 1. Home(Just a Welcome Page without js), 2. Pokelist(calls the API and shows the first 151 Pokemon), 3. Details (THe one where I want to show the details of the selected Pokemon), I have to use RouterLink.
I am clueless about doing something like this and found out a way of send the id of the selected Pokemon into the "Description" component's link (Bulbasaur puts a "1" at the end of the link for instance) the thing is that I can't get that id into the API call bit I can display it in an h3 for example.
I don't know another way of getting the id from the pokeList component in the Description component to get only that Pokemon information using router link, I'm a beginner Here is my Pokelist code:

PokeList Component

```
<div class="row">
          <div v-for="pokemon in pokemons" :key="pokemon.id" class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card-image">
              

              
              <div class="card-sl">
                <router-link :to="'/pokemon/' + pokemon.id">
        <img :src="pokemon.sprites.front_default" @click=" redirectToDescription(pokemon.id)" />
      </router-link> <!--This sends you to the new component with the selected pokemon Id at the end-->
              </div>
              <div class="card-heading">
                <h3 class="pokemonName">{{ pokemon.name }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-text">
                <p>Base Experience: {{ pokemon.base_experience }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';


export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
        return {
          pokemons: [],
          
        };
    },
    setup() {
        const pokemons = ref([]);
        onMounted(async () => {
            try {
                for (let index = 1; index < 152; index++) {
                    const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}`);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    //console.log(response.data.moves);
                    pokemons.value.push(response.data); // Push each Pokemon data to the reactive array
                    
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
        return {
            pokemons
        };
  },
  methods: {
    redirectToDescription(pokemonId) {
      this.$router.push('/pokemon/' + pokemonId);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now, in the new component i try to get that id number from the link but it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$route')"

Describe Component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Pokemon Description</h2>
        <p>{{ this.$route.params.id }}</p> <!--This is the only way i found to get the id and here it works-->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
        return {
          pokemons: [],
          
        };
    },
    setup() {
        
        const pokemons = ref([]);
        
        onMounted(async () => {
            try {
                const pokemonId = this.$route.params.id;
                    const response = await 
//Here, i try to use the method to get the id biut i get the said error, if i just put a number it works but it needs to throw the previously selected pokemon id to get all the info of that specific pokemon
axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`); 
                    console.log(response.data);
                    //console.log(response.data.moves);
                    pokemons.value.push(response.data); // Push each Pokemon data to the reactive array
                console.log(pokemonId);
                
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
        return {
            pokemons
        };
  }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering in the Describe component is because you're trying to access **$route** directly within the **setup()** function. In **Vue 3**, the **composition API**, including the **setup()** function, doesn't have access to the instance's properties and methods like **$route**.

To access route information in a composition API component, you can use the **useRoute** function from the **vue-router** package. Here's how you can modify your Describe component to get the **id** parameter from the route:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Details</h1>
    <div v-for="pokemon in pokemons" :key="pokemon.id">
      <h3>{{ pokemon.name }}</h3>
      <!-- Display other details of the Pokemon -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  name: "Describe",
  setup() {
    const pokemons = ref([]);
    const route = useRoute();

    onMounted(async () => {
      try {
        const pokemonId = route.params.id;
        const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`);
        pokemons.value.push(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });

    return {
      pokemons
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

In this updated code, we import the **useRoute** function from **vue-router** and then call it within the **setup()** function to get the current route information. We assign it to the route constant. From **route.params.id**, we extract the **id** parameter that was passed in the URL.

Now, you can access the **id** parameter in your **axios** call and retrieve the details of the specific Pokemon. The fetched data is then pushed to the **pokemons** array, which you can iterate over in the template to display the Pokemon's details.

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried to use that import but directly on "from 'vue';" and go errors, thanks for helping me

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).